# Unable to find maximum value of my custom function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, maximum

```
myfunn[x_, y_] := Module[{},
If[x < 5, Return[0]];
   If[x < 10, Return[2]];
   x*y];
```

I'm unable to find the maximum value of this function over the following range of x: 0<=x<=20 when y=0 using the **NMaxValue**, **NMaximize** or **FindMaximum** commands

```
NMaximize[{myfunn[x, 0], 0 <= x <= 20}, x]

NMaxValue[{myfunn[x, 0], 0 <= x <= 20}, x]
```

All of them return 0 while the answer I'm expecting is 2. Is there anyway to get Mathematica to compute the expected answer? Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you do `Clear[myfunn]` followed by the definition `myfunn[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := ...`? Alternatively, use `Piecewise` instead of `If`.

Comment: Thank you. myfunn[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ]  seems to work although I'm not yet sure why (I'm a light Mathematica user)

Comment: That's because when you call your function with symbolic arguments, the `If` statements never get activated. Check: `myfunn[x,y]` returns `x y`.

Comment: What I meant to say is that in your definition, the argument `myfunn[x,0]` is immediately simplified to `0` before ever putting a numerical value in for `x`. The `If` statements thus never get to see any numerical values for `x`.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
myfunn[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{0, x < 5}, {2, x < 10}}, x y];

NMaximize[{myfunn[x, 0], 0 <= x <= 20}, x]
```

> {2., {x -> 6.91445}}

```
NMaxValue[{myfunn[x, 0], 0 <= x <= 20}, x]
```

> 2.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
myfunn[x_, y_] := If[x<5,0,If[x<10,2,x*y]];

NMaxValue[{myfunn[x, 0], 0<=x<=20}, x]
```

> 2